# What percent of the population could vote in Venice between 900 and 1200 AD?

Tags: venice

Venice's political institutions became much more inclusive between 900 and 1200 AD especially with the creation of the Consilium Sapientis. How many of Venice's population were citizens entitled to vote as part of the Concio for members of the Consilium Sapientis and the Doge?

I've checked wikipedia and done some rather extensive research on Venice. It seems [about 5% of the population were patricians](https://cassio-nation.wikispaces.com/Life+in+Venice+during+the+Renaissance), but non-patrician citizens could also vote, and I haven't found any estimates for the proportion of people who were citizens.

Comment: There's actually rather a lot about Medieval Venetian politics in [Shadow of the Lion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shadow_of_the_Lion). Its a work of alternate history (aka: fiction), but one of the authors is a degreed historian, and it was clearly exhaustively researched. (Also one of my favorite books I've ever read). From there, it appears that the family heads kind of decided who it would be ahead of time, and votes were just a formality to give the common folk some feeling of investment in the new Doge. (This isn't an answer due to the sourcing, but it may give someone a start).

Answer (score 3):

I found [this reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=RVEbVtJkjE0C&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=venetian%20republic%20percent%20of%20citizens%20-italy&source=bl&ots=_yUHXuyvp2&sig=TrKY1NZoYMfUUNnvLHrQUh6wG1s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeycyp_aLLAhVU-WMKHf6vAkAQ6AEIHTAA#v=snippet&q=percent%20citizens&f=false), Venice in Environmental Peril?: Myth and Reality
By Dominic Standish, citing that about 4% of the population were patricians and about 6% were citizens "leaving about 90% powerless".

Answer (score -2):

[Hazlitt's book](https://archive.org/details/venetianrepublic01hazl) might be helpful, though dated.

Comment: Could you please include the conclusions you got from the book? Because simply stating a source is very rarely helpful...